# How to update the value through PUT method when using angular x-editable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Trying to use angular x-editable I've set up frontend for the project and I don't know how to send the request from javascript to my controller update action to update the value. After refreshing the page nothing changes. Does anybody know how to do it?

**tasks_controller**

```
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:id, :title, :due_date, :priority, :complete)
  end
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <a href="#" editable-text="task.title">{{ task.title }}</a>
</div>
```

**tasks.js**

```
var app = angular.module('Todolist', ['xeditable']);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.task = {
    title: 'awesome task'
  };

});
```

**rake routes**

```
PUT    /users/:user_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sending isn't really related to the *Angular-xeditable* since it just modifies the value in the scope (*$scope.task.title* in your case). What you want to do is either [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for value changes or use button to submit the data to the server.

To send the HTTP PUT request, you can use for example Angular's vanilla [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). With *$http* you can do

```
$http.put('/users/' + $scope.userId + '/tasks' + $scope.taskId, {task: $scope.task}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Here I have assumed that you have *$scope.userId* and *$scope.taskId* defined.

Now you can include that inside of watch like this

```
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // Here do the above $http.put
});
```

or with HTML button like this

```
<button ng-click="sendPut();">Call backend</button>
```

with controller code such as

```
$scope.sendPut = function () {
  // Here do the above $http.put
}
```